# Powershell Test-Path output -eq "False" not working

Tags: powershell, path

So I'm trying to check if the Path is available. I do this with the Test-Path

It looks like this:

```
$c="C:\"
$d="D:\"
$e="E:\"

if(Test-Path $c -eq "False"){
}
elseif(Test-Path $d -eq "False"){
}
elseif(Test-Path $e -eq "False"){
}
else{
"The File doesn't exist"
}
```

So what am I doing wrong if the error looks like this:

```
Test-Path : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'eq'.
At C:\Users\boriv\Desktop\ps\Unbenannt1.ps1:23 char:17
+ If(Test-Path $c -eq "False"){
+                 ~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Test-Path], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestPathCommand`
```

Comment: `if((Test-Path $c) -eq $False){ }`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You wan't to compare the result of the `Test-Path` cmdlet so you need to use parentheses otherwise the `-eq` parameter gets passed to the `Test-Path` cmdlet and thats the reason why you get the error.

I would use the `-not` operator since I found it more readable. Example:

```
if(-not (Test-Path $c)) {
}
```

Comment: I like your solution. This why I'm going to accept your anwer  as the right one. But both answers are right.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap your `Test-Path $c` in parentheses so they get evaluated first:

```
$c="C:\"
$d="D:\"
$e="E:\"

if((Test-Path $c) -eq "False"){
    Write-Output '$c is false'
}
elseif((Test-Path $d) -eq "False"){
    Write-Output '$d is false'
}
elseif((Test-Path $e) -eq "False"){
    Write-Output '$e is false'
}
else{
    "The File doesn't exist"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The other option instead of using `if/elseif/else` is to put the paths into an array and loop through it until you find a valid path.

This way the code stays the same for any number of paths.

```
$paths = "C:\","D:\","E:\"

foreach ($path in $paths) {
    if(Test-Path $path){
        $validpath = $path
        break
    }
}

if ($validpath){
    "File exists here: $validpath"
}
else {
    "The File doesn't exist in any path"
}
```